# how to implement "saving as" option in html with python?

Tags: html, python-2.7, selenium, beautifulsoup, save

I'm trying to fetch a file from a website which is a `.edf` file. When I click on it, it opens the corresponding text view in the browser. But if I save the content as to a directory everything works fine.

And the question is since I have a lot of file like this I wanted to use python to fetch all of them automatically and save in a directory. So, how can I use beautifulsoup or selenium or any library to get this file in a directory just like using "saving as" option?

*note:* Reading the file with using `soup.read()` and trying to write on a `.edf` file is not working.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res=urllib2.urlopen('https://www.physionet.org/pn4/eegmmidb/S001/S001R03.edf')    

html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

testfile = open('tfile.edf','w')
testfile.write(soup.encode('utf-8'))
testfile.close()
```

It's working but the data is not contains in `.edf` file as reading the html content.

There is a image file in below which may explain my purpose.

Basically and shortly what I'm trying to do is saving the file content in a specific directory with using python.

[image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDOvw.png)

Comment: Your question is not specific enough, explain what you have tried with an example if possible and explanation of which part is not providing the expected results. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.

Comment: ok! How about now? It's really hard to explain such a thing. I'm struggling with the words to explain to this case.

Comment: This looks much better. Someone with more domain knowledge should be able to answer this question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure out how to do it. If anyone wants to learn here is the answer.

```
import urllib    
urllib.urlretrieve('link','file to be save')
```

you can easly save the file with this code!